# link hover stoped by text

Tags: html, css, hover

Help i work on hover link effect, the effect is opacity. The effect is working but it stop when i hover the caption inside it its stop the effect.
here the code of the css:

```css
a .hover11 img {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

a .hover11 img:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}

.imagebig {
  position: relative;
  width: 24%;
  /* for IE 6 */
  height: 60%;
  background: #D9138E;
  background: linear-gradient(#D9138E, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  border: solid 1px #FFFFFF;
  display: inline-block;
}

h2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
```

```html
<a href="">
  <div class="imagebig hover11" align="left">
    <img style="width:100%; height:100%" src="//placehold.it/100" alt="" />
    <h2>Kung Fu Panda</h2>
  </div>
</a>
```

The last one is the html. Is there anyway to stop the h2 stopping the effect when hover ? I already try user-select its not work

Comment: There's no `<a>` tag in your code. And you could have at least used the Tidy button there.

Comment: sorry lemme edit that i copy wrong thing

Comment: Boss, your HTML code is not semantically right. You can't have any block elements inside `<a>` and you have two!

Comment: Also, you should make sure you are demonstrating the issue here. Now it does after my edit.

Comment: I just try that sorry it doesnt work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add `pointer-events: none;` this will prevent the hover effect on `h2`

```css
a .hover11 img {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

a .hover11 img:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}

.imagebig {
  position: relative;
  width: 24%;
  /* for IE 6 */
  height: 60%;
  background: #D9138E;
  background: linear-gradient(#D9138E, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  border: solid 1px #FFFFFF;
  display: inline-block;
}

h2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="">
  <div class="imagebig hover11" align="left">
    <img style="width:100%; height:100%" src="//placehold.it/100" alt="" />
    <h2>Kung Fu Panda</h2>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, its working. I dont know about that event yet so i learn new thing now thanks :)

Comment: you are welcome, you could mark my answer as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
a .hover11:hover img {
    opacity: .5;
}
```

instead of this :

```
a .hover11 img:hover{
    opacity: .5;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much it work too. I didnt even think about trying like that thanks :D

Comment: youre wellcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have given hover effect on image tag only that's the reason your hover effect don't work on text. 
So instead of giving hover effect on image tag **give hover effect on outer div** and it will work for both image as well as text.

**Use this:**

```
a .hover11:hover img {
  opacity: .5;
}
```